# Windows. Docker Desktop do not start. Error: "exec: "rundll32": executable file not found in %PATH%"

Tags: windows, docker, environment-variables, docker-desktop

Docker Desktop do not start. "exec: "rundll32": executable file not found in %PATH%"

Need to be updated "environment variables".

Added to the %PATH% variable this line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32"

Additionaly was added "C:\WINDOWS\system32" to the Path (Optional)

[image]

Restart docker.

Hope it will save hours for someone.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the below path in the environment variables and restart the docker, it will work. I configured this to sign in to the docker desktop.

C:\windows\system32